# DropDownList from object

Tags: c#, .net, drop-down-menu

How do you bind a DropDownlist DataText or DataValue field from a object. 
When the object in question is at a second level, e.g. the object to bind is not in the first level of the returned object Users.ContactDetails.Telephone, as the code below doesn't work:

```
ddl.DataSource = dal.dal_Users.GetAllUsers();
ddl.DataTextField = "Telephone";
```

I have tried a range of ideas but can't seem to find any information on if this can be done or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**  I got enough feedback about this topic that I felt it was worthy of a [blog post](http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2009/06/24/Working-with-a-select-box-using-Model-View-Presenter)

One approach that I took when binding domain objects to ddl controls is to inherit from a base class that has an overload in the constr to allow for a text/value only "subset" of the original.  The code below is used in a Model View Presenter Or Model View ViewModel implementation that abstracts out the ddl control so you can push any UI on the top of this business code.

**below is an example of how I bind a ddl with a collection of user objects, and set the selected based on the related object (unit of work)**

```
 public void PopulateUserDDL(UnitOfWork UnitOfWorkObject)
 {
     List<User> UserCollection = mUserService.GetUserCollection();  //get a collection of objects to bind this ddl

     List<ILookupDTO> UserLookupDTO = new List<ILookupDTO>();

     UserLookupDTO.Add(new User(" ", "0"));
     //insert a blank row ... if you are into that type of thing

     foreach (var User in UserCollection) {
         UserLookupDTO.Add(new User(User.FullName, User.ID.ToString()));
     }

     LookupCollection LookupCollectionObject = new LookupCollection(UserLookupDTO);
     LookupCollectionObject.BindTo(mView.UserList);

     if (UnitOfWorkObject == null) {
         return;
     }

     if (UserCollection == null) {
         return;
     }

     for (i = 0; i <= UserCollection.Count - 1; i++) {
         if (UserCollection(i).ID == UnitOfWorkObject.User.ID) {
             LookupCollectionObject.SelectedIndex = (i + 1);
             //because we start at 0 instead of 1 (we inserted the blank row above)
             break;
         }
     }
 }
```

**below is what the overload will look like in your user object**

```
/// <summary>
/// This constr is used when you want to create a new Lookup Collection of ILookupDTO
/// </summary>
/// <param name="txt">The text that will show up for the user in the lookup collection</param>
/// <param name="val">The value that will be attached to the item in the lookup collection</param>
/// <remarks></remarks>
public New(string txt, string val) : base(txt, val)
{
}
```

**below will be needed in the base class for any Entity/Domain Objects/DTO/etc**

```
 public New(string txt, string val)
 {
     mText = txt;
     mValue = val;
 }
```

**this base class should also implement ILookupDTO - because this will force you to make public a Text and Value property that are used by the user object in this example**

```
 public interface ILookupDTO
 {
     string Text {
         get;
         set;
     }
     string Value {
         get;
         set;
     }
 }
```

**the below is the def for LookupCollection used in the bind method at the top of this answer**

```
 public class LookupCollection
 {
     private readonly IEnumerable<ILookupDTO> dtos;
     private ILookupList mList;

     public LookupCollection(IEnumerable<ILookupDTO> dtos)
     {
         this.dtos = dtos;
     }

     public void BindTo(ILookupList list)
     {
         mList = list;

         mList.Clear();

         foreach (ILookupDTO dto in dtos) {
             mList.Add(dto);
         }
     }

     public int SelectedIndex {
         get { return mList.SelectedIndex; }
         set { mList.SelectedIndex = value; }
     }

     public string SelectedValue {
         get { return mList.SelectedValue; }
         set { mList.SelectedValue = value; }
     }
 }
```

**below is the interface for ILookupList - used in the implementation of each UI specific control (see the web and wpf examples below)**

```
 public interface ILookupList
 {
     void Add(ILookupDTO dto);
     void Clear();
     int Count();
     int SelectedIndex {
         get;
         set;
     }
     string SelectedValue {
         get;
         set;
     }
 }
```

**now in your code-behind you will need to do something like this in your read only property for the view**

Return New WebLookupList(ddlUsers)

**here is an implementation for a web specific ddl**

```
 public class WebLookupList : ILookupList
 {

     private readonly ListControl listControl;

     public WebLookupList(ListControl listControl)
     {
         this.listControl = listControl;
     }

     public void Clear()
     {
         listControl.Items.Clear();
     }

     public void Add(Interfaces.ILookupDTO dto)
     {
         listControl.Items.Add(new ListItem(dto.Text, dto.Value));
     }

     public int Count()
     {
         return listControl.Items.Count;
     }

     public int SelectedIndex {
         get { return listControl.SelectedIndex; }
         set { listControl.SelectedIndex = value; }
     }

     public string SelectedValue {
         get { return listControl.SelectedValue; }
         set { listControl.SelectedValue = value; }
     }
 }
```

**here is the implementation for a WPF specific ddl**
**if using wpf your read only property for the view would look like - Return New WPFLookupList(ddlUsers)**

```
 public class WPFLookupList : ILookupList
 {

     private readonly ComboBox combobox;

     public WPFLookupList(ComboBox combobox)
     {
         this.combobox = combobox;
     }

     public void Add(Interfaces.ILookupDTO dto)
     {
         ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
         item.Content = dto.Text;
         item.Tag = dto.Value;

         combobox.Items.Add(item);
     }

     public void Clear()
     {
         combobox.Items.Clear();
     }

     public int Count()
     {
         return combobox.Items.Count;
     }

     public int SelectedIndex {
         get { return combobox.SelectedIndex; }
         set { combobox.SelectedIndex = value; }
     }

     public string SelectedValue {
         get { return combobox.SelectedValue.Tag; }
         set { combobox.SelectedValue.Tag = value; }
     }
 }
```

**You only need 1 of these at a time, but I thought showing both would help make clear what we are abstracting away**

Because this was such a huge answer, I could post a sample project for download showing this in action if requested - let me know

Answer (score 5):

If you are using C# 3 then you can use the `ConvertAll<>` etension method to create a new anonymous type that moves the inner property up to the top level.

Try something like this:

```
IEnumerable<User> users = dal.dal_Users.GetAllUsers();

ddl.DataSource = users.ConvertAll(u => 
    new { Value = u.Name, Telephone = u.ContactDetails.Telephone });
ddl.DataTextField = "Telephone";
```

Comment: ConvertAll<T> is not an extension method and exists in .NET 2.0. It is a method on List<T>. Select() is as described.

Answer (score 1):

The only way i can see that this could be done in .Net 2.0 would be something like this

```
  List<Users> userList = dal_Users.GetAllUsers();

  foreach (Users u in userList )
  {
     ListItem li = new ListItem();
     li.Text = u.ContactDetails.Telephone;
     li.Value = u.userID.ToString();
     ddl.Items.Add(li);
  }

  ddl.DataBind();
```